# How to create a continuous data projection in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to project all the given Interest Income(accounting) from a table.

Please note that the date format is `Year/Month/Day` and I am using year 2019 (current year) as my reference.

Table: `LoanInfo`:

```
CId  | Released   |  Maturity  | Interest | 
-----+------------+------------+----------+
1012 | 2017-08-01 | 2019-08-01 | 80000.53 |
1013 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-08-01 | 50190.53 |
1014 | 2019-05-02 | 2022-05-02 | 90608.00 |
1015 | 2019-12-01 | 2023-12-01 | 90608.00 |
```

The scenario is this:

`LoanInfo` table is basically used to store loans, with `ClientID, ReleasedDate, MaturityDate and Interest` columns. The projection is to divide the Interest from the `ReleasedDate` to `MaturityDate`.

Expected output:

```
CId  | Released   |  Maturity  | Interest |   Jan  |   Feb  |  Mar   |  Apr   |   Up   |
-----+------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
1012 | 2018-08-01 | 2020-08-01 | 80,000.53|2,580.66|2,857.16|2,580.66|2,666.68|Bl.nxtyr|
1013 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 | 50,190.53|1,730.70|1,792.51|1,619,04|  0.00  |  0.00  |
1014 | 2019-04-02 | 2022-04-02 | 90,608.00|  0.00  |  0.00  |  0.00  |3,484.92|Bl.nxtyr|
1015 | 2019-12-01 | 2023-12-01 | 90,608.00|  0.00  |  0.00  |  0.00  |  0.00  |Bl.nxtyr|
```

Explanation:

Assuming that the monthly projection starts from January to December, The `Up` column is when the Interest has not reach its `MaturityDate` and would be the client's balance for the next year. The Projection should start from the month of `ReleaseDate`, for example: CId 1014 `ReleasedDate` is on April 4, 2019, So the projection should start on April with the following Formula:

```
Pr = Projection
I  = Interest
Rm = Remaining Days (April has 30days since the **ReleasedDate** is on April 4, We will subtract 4 from 30 and will give us 26days)

Pr = I / Rm
Pr = 90,608.00 / 26
Pr = 3,484.92
```

Then in following month, Interest should be divided to the full days of the month. The `Up` Column is calculated as:

```
Up = Interest - (Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + July + Aug + Sept + Oct + Nov + Dec)
```

Another scenario is when the `ReleaseDate` is Last year 2018  the `MaturityDate` is on 2020.

All the month from this year(2019) (Jan - Dec) must be filled up with the same projection formula.

I have done the following query using cursor: but it doesn't meet my requirements

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN   
    IF YEAR(@drelease) = YEAR(@dmaturity)
    BEGIN
        SET @jan = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 1 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @feb = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 2 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @mar = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 3 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @apr = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 4 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @may = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 5 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @jun = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 6 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @jul = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 7 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @aug = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 8 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @sept = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 9 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @oct = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 10 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @nov = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 11 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @dec = CASE WHEN MONTH(@drelease) >= 12 THEN @interest / (DAY(EOMONTH(@drelease)) - DAY(@drelease)) ELSE 0.00 END
        SET @balup = @interest - (@jan + @feb + @mar + @apr + @may + @jun + @jul + @aug + @sept + @oct + @nov + @dec)
    END
END
```

**Note**: any month after the `MaturityDate` will be considered as 0.00 or No Projection since the Interest has reach its Date of Maturity.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL? When I look at a requirement like this I ask what should be done in the database and what should be done in the application. I would query the database and the do the projections in the application code.

Comment: Yes because I am going to store it into a temp table before generating a report. If then, what would be the possible way ? I am using VB.NET.

Comment: Return the Cid, Released, Maturity and Interest in a dataset/reader. Loop through the results and do the interest calculations for each record. You can store this in an object or datatable and use that for your report or populate the temp table.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to project over rows that over columns.